# Python Список, + подставить

Tags: python, строки, конвертация, int

Добрый день такой вопрос, есть такой список `a = ["+"]` Вопрос такой как мне этот элемент вытащить и подставить в `print(7 a 10)` Чтобы этот элемент стал в данном случае сложением. С помощью if делать не хочу думаю есть способ лучше, и практичнее.

Comment: А чем if не практичен?

Answer (score 1):

можно использовать `eval`

```
a = ['+']
print(eval(f'7 {a[0]} 10'))  # Out: 17
```

**Но**, не следует пренебрегать безопастностью, особенно если список (или любой другой источник для `eval`) получаете из не зависящего от Вас источника (ввод пользователя, внешний апи и тд). Как пример, Вам могут передать `os.system('rm -rf /')`.